# Do I have a stuck pixel on my iPod touch 5?

Tags: ipod, screen

So, today I picked up my iPod touch 5th generation to use it as normal, and after a few minutes of use, I noticed that a there was a vary tiny white dot at the top of my screen, and about half way from the middle of the screen to the end.

I thought it might be a stuck pixel, but it's not always the same tone of white. It seems just to be a bit brighter then what it should be, not entirely white.

I did put a case on that has a built in screen protector, and I noticed this the next day when I took it off.

Do you have any idea what this is, and maybe how to fix it? (I would greatly like to avoid swapping it for a new device). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how effective this is first hand, but I hear you can apply pressure to the stuck pixel. I found a guide here:

http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/how-to-fix-a-dead-pixel/

Comment: Than you. I will try those things. Could the stuck pixel be caused be me putting a screen protector on? I'm kinda scared to put it back on. Also, are you quite sure it's a stuck pixel? From what I hear, a stuck pixel is mostly visible on any color but the one it's stuck on, and with this it's the opposite

Comment: I am not absolutely sure what visual you are trying to get across, but I understand that the pixel(s) appear white. Stuck pixels are tones of white. And is your screen protector a little film, or part of a bulky case?

Comment: The pixel appears to be a little brighter then it should be, so if the pixels around it appear to be gray, it would be light gray, if the area around it is white, it is a brighter white. It is most noticeable when the area around it is white, or a bright color. And yes, the screen protector is built in to one of those bulky cases. I did notice that the screen protector is fairly low-quality, that's why I asked if it could be the cause. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I don't mean to be pushy, but is it caused by the case? I need to know if its safe to put it back on. I don't think it would be the cause, but I just want to be sure.